# iPhone X vs iPad media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design

I see the interwebz agree on these media queries for:

iPhone X

```
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width : 375px)
  and (max-device-width : 812px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
  and (orientation : landscape) { }
```

iPad

```
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 768px)
  and (max-device-width: 1024px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
  and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

This way though, iPad-specific styles override iPhone X's ones on the iPhone X.

Is there a way to distinguish them better?

Comment: Swap the media queries around. But what do you need this for? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to have separate css for iPhone X and iPad, as per my question. I don't think the specifics matter.

Comment: I was just curious what you were going to do with the different kinds of iPads, which have the same resolution in CSS pixels, but different device pixel ratios.

Answer (score 0):

iPad and iPhone X has distinct aspect ratios, adding

```
and (device-aspect-ratio: 4/3)
```

(3/4 for portrait) to the ipad media query solves the problem.